# Formatting Date and Time on a table populated with mysql

Tags: mysql, date, html-table, format

I have Date and Time fields stored on mysql database, which have a very ugly unix format (applied by mysql).

In order to adapt this format to a more familiar one and echo it on the screen, I would fetch the date and bind it to a variable `$mydate`, so then I just format it this way.

```
$mydate= new DateTime($mydate);
$mydate=date_format($mydate,"d/m/Y");
```

This works perfect for me.

Now I have a new challenge: I want to build a table in which I have a Date and Time fields which I have to format somehow too. So here´s my code till now:

```
if ($arch = $pdo->prepare("SELECT date, time, info FROM tblinfo WHERE idinfo = ?")) { 
  $arch ->execute(array($idpac));   
  $data = $arch->fetchAll();
  echo '<div class="cool_table" ><table><tr><td>TIME</td><td >DATE</td><td>INFO</td></tr>';
  foreach ($data as $row){
  echo '<tr>';
  foreach ($row as $col){
  echo '<td>'.$col.'</td>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</table></div>';    
}
```

So this generates a very cool table for me. But I cant seem to figure out how can I format the Date and Time using this code. Can someone help me with this one?

Comment: It's not an "ugly" unix format. It's the native mysql yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format. If you want it to show up as something else, then RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you format the date directly in the query, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m/%d/%Y') AS formateddate, 
  TIME_FORMAT(time,'%H:%i') AS formatedtime, 
  info 
FROM tblinfo 
WHERE idinfo = ?
```

**EDIT**

swapped arguments as from comment by @azirion

Comment: Excellent idea Eugen. Just had to flip the code a bit for the DATE_FORMAT, you have it backwards it should read: DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m/%d/%Y',) AS formateddate, TIME_FORMAT(time,'%H:%i') AS formatedtime... Now it works like a charm! thanks :D

Comment: Good catch, seems I am finally getting old!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried googling LANGUAGE OBJECT OPERATION which yields PHP DateTime Format, and returns as one of the first results:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Is that page any help?  The technique generalizes. :)